# There are class methods. Can I have class attributes?

Tags: python, inheritance

Consider the code snippet for the base class `Base` and its two child classes `ChildA` and `ChildB`:

```
class Base():
    map = {}

    def __init__(self, x):
        type(self).map[x] = self

    @classmethod
    def get_state(cls, x):
        if x in cls.map:
             return cls.map[x]
        return None

class ChildA(Base):
    pass

class ChildB(Base):
    pass
```

When creating an instance `a = ChildA('foo')` and calling `ChildB.get_state('foo')` after this, it returns the instance of `ChildA`.

However, expected (or rather the wishful behaviour) was `None`. The `map` attribute seems to be attached to the parent class `Base`, and the child classes *share* it.

Of course I could simply add a specific attribute to the child classes

```
class ChildA(Base):
    map = {}

class ChildB(Base):
    map = {}
```

but this is verbose if you have many child classes and several of those attributes. Is there any way to solve this by inheritance from `Base`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [init subclass hook](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/):

```
class Base:
    def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
        cls.map = {}
```

Demo:

```
>>> class ChildA(Base): 
...     ... 
...
>>> class ChildB(Base): 
...     ... 
...
>>> ChildA.map == ChildB.map == {}
True
>>> ChildA.map is ChildB.map
False
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was thinking of creating a class method that would do this, but it would have to be called externally